# Should I use salt to authenticate data?

Tags: cryptography, web-application, authentication, hash

I have a client and a server. The client makes a request containing userId, cardId, position (on the card)

A hacker could just do the same http request with the next position. So I think about creating a hash for the data. Using plain MD5 won't be enough.

Would it be secure enough to have some salt added? Like `md5(userId + cardId + position + "a very long random string")`?

Comment: It all depends. Exactly what attacks are you trying to prevent, and how do you discern a "real" user with non-malicious intent from a "hacker" (who could very well be a real user) with malicious intent?

Comment: I think you might want to ask this on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ Also, you should consider the fact that md5 is vulnerable to collision attacks, so it won't matter if you salt it or not, an attacker could efficiently brute-force it. I guess SHA512 is a better alternative.

Comment: The client is an App running on a smartphone. Only the App on the client should be able to send valid messages to the server. So a hacker shouldn't be able to generate a valid message, i.e. a valid hash. So by monitoring the network trafic he can figure out all the data (userId (some String), cardId (some String) and position (integer)). He can't use this data anymore, as that position, on that cardId is now blocked by the server. But he could try to +1 on the position. That's why I must make it imposible for him to be able to generate the hash himself.

Comment: @D-32, your previous comment is wrong, and does not take into account the possibility of malicious users, aka "hackers". In order to find a proper security solution, you must take into account the full risk profile - e.g. it is possible for an attacker to fake messages to the server, or intercept valid messages from the app. I suggest you move this question (ask a moderator) to [security.se] - I think you'd get a better picture there!

Comment: @D-32 But what would happen if someone increments the position? And why does the client needs to remember this position and why doesn’t the server do it?

Comment: @Gumbo the idea on the hash is exactly that nobody can just increment the position (because he doen't know how to generate the hash). If the server does it, the request will always look the same, and therefor easy to fake.

Comment: @D-32 But why does the client need to provide this *position* parameter anyways? And what happens when he is able to provide another valid *position* value?

Comment: There is only one valid position-value, that is +1 from the one before. Yes I know, the server doen't need that information, but it makes the request unique. So if the hash can't be created without the app, there's no possibility on predicting the next request / next hash. So the thing is I have to know if the hash-creation is save.

Comment: Why don't you simply throw SSL at the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you generate the random string on the client then you cannot compute the same hash. If you do it on the server then you have to send it ti the client. So this scheme won't work by itself.

If you distribute the salt (more or less a symmetric key) with the application then you can easily retrieve it from the client code. You are better off to send an RSA public key with your application and encrypt the password with it. However you might as well create an SSL session from the client and be much more *sure* you are safe.

It's more something for crypto, but you are better off using a scheme that includes SSL as performing any scheme without at least server authentication and key agreement/secure messaging will likely fail...

Comment: The problem is the server needs the same random string, otherwise it can't check that the message + hash has been generated by the client-application. I just thought I could hardcode that String into both applications?

Comment: Ammended answer. The string would be easily retrievable by anyone using the application.

Comment: May I ask how that would be possible?

Comment: Which part? The SSL part or using a public key?

Comment: How would it be posible for to retrieve the string?

Comment: From an application? Very easily, but the exact method would depend on the platform. A hexeditor makes it easy to extract it from a C++ compiled windows application; most of the strings are in a table that can easily be found. You can obfuscate the string (or actually, the byte array) a bit, but that will only be a slight bump in the road for any hacker with some expertise.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15519/discussion-between-d-32-and-owlstead)

Answer (score 1):

No.  Salt is not an authenticator.  Salt is not a secure way to authenticate requests from the client.

A more complete answer is: You should back up, and do a requirements analysis and a risk analysis.  Figure out what your security goals are, and what the threat model is.  What resources are you protecting?  What kinds of attacks might someone have an incentive to mount?  Once you've been able to think that through, *then* you can start thinking about a particular mechanism.

At present, you do not seem to be able to give a clear description of what you are trying to accomplish.  Therefore, the question is ill-posed and you are not likely to receive a good answer.

With such sparse information, the best advice I can give you is: use SSL (https).  While I cannot be sure, due to the sparsity of the information give -- it sounds like you are probably reinventing the wheel, and probably poorly.  Also, I recommend that you store state information on the server side, rather than storing it on the client and trusting the client to be honest about reporting the current state (after all, a malicious client can always lie -- a md5 hash does not prevent that).